# Integer homology of SO(n)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, direct-sum

I'm reading Hatcher's Algebraic topology, where is said:

Proposition 3D.3 (Page 299.): $H_∗(SO(n); Z)$ is a direct sum of $Z$’s and $Z_2$’s.

The claim is that there are chain complex isomorphisms $C_∗(SO(2k + 1))≈ C^2⊗C^4⊗··· ⊗C^{2k}$ and 
$C_∗(SO(2k + 2))≈C^2⊗C^4⊗ ··· ⊗C^{2k}⊗C^{2k+1}$, where $C^{2k+1}$ has basis $e^0$ and $e^{2k+1}$ and $C^{2i}$ is subcomplex of $C_∗(SO(n))$
with basis the cells $e^0$, $e^{2i}$, $e^{2i−1}$ and $e^{2i}e^{2i−1}$.

My question is: **why this isomorphisms hold and how to prove that boundary maps agree?**

I would be welcome for detailed answers in order to understand this better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Projection onto the last column $p:SO(n)\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $SO(n-1)$. The sphere has a CW-decomposition with two cells, one in dimension zero and one in dimension $n-1$. Use the spectral sequence of a fibration and induction on $n$ to build up to his answer. George Whitehead gives a nice explanation in his book on homotopy theory.