# Can $X=SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\}$be homeomorphic to or homotopic equivalent to product of spheres?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

$SO(n)$ is the special orthogonal group.Let $X=SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\},I_n$ is the identity matrix.Is $X$ homeomorphic to or homotopic equivalent to product of spheres?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\pi_1(SO(n))=\mathbb{Z/2}.$ What happens when you remove a point?

Comment: Actually,I want to calculate the homology group of $X=SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\}$,if the above property was satisfied,I can calculate the homology group easily.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, if you consider the fundamental group you see that there is no hope in this direction, because the fundamental group of a product of spheres will always be trivial.

Comment: Would you mind giving me more hints on calculating the homology group of  $X=SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\}$

Comment: For instance when you remove a point from a connected $n$-dimensional manifold, it deformation retracts onto its $n-1$ skeleton, so the $n$-th homology group is now trivial.

Comment: You also may want to have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059070/integer-homology-of-son

Comment: Sorry,I am not familar with the concept of  skeleton.What is the $n-1$ skelton of  $SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\}$?

Comment: It is a CW complex of dimension $n-1$ and that is all that matters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71860/discussion-between-mathrookie-and-arnaud-mortier).

Comment: For instance the $n-1$ skeleton of a usual torus is a wedge of $2$ circles.

Comment: What is $n−1$  skeleton of  $SO(n)\setminus\{I_n\}$.Is it the wedge of $S^_{n-1}$?